# How to change CounterTextAppearance

Tags: android

I'm implementing counter in my app.
At the moment I would like to implement a custom color and style for the counter. To do this I created the following style among my themes:

```
 <style name="CounterTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/karla_bold</item>
        <item name="counterTextColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="counterMaxLength">60</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    </style>
```

This is called within my textView:

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reason_layout"
                    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_margin_top"
                    android:hint="@string/bullettin_reason_field"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterTextAppearance"
                    app:error="@{bindingViewModel.reasonValidator.error}"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:helperText="@string/reason_helper_text"
                    app:helperTextEnabled="true"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/code_layout">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_reason"
                        style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:maxLength="60"
                        android:text="@={bindingViewModel.reasonLiveData}"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The problem is that no style is applied and I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
Changing parent counter style not change yet

@font/karla_bold
@color/red
13sp

Comment: `counterTextColor` and `counterMaxLength` are not `TextAppearance` attributes, so they will be ignored there. Those are `TextInputLayout` attributes, and they would have to be applied to the `TextInputLayout`. To change the color in a `TextAppearance`, set the `android:textColor` attribute instead. Beyond that, I would expect `app:counterTextAppearance` to  work as advertised. Were the font and size not working, too?

Comment: Hi @MikeM. thanks for your attention. I would like to change counter text color, set new counter font family and set counter text bold style. I'm using app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterTextAppearance" now. I've changed parent from syle as follow, but not change the result. Counter il always the same.

<style name="CounterTextAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

Comment: You don't want a `Widget` parent for a `TextAppearance` style. If anything, you can change it to `TextAppearance.Design.Counter`, but it needs to be a `TextAppearance` to use with `app:counterTextAppearance`. Also, are you sure the font family works on its own? Have you tested that on a regular `TextView` to make sure it's set up correctly and that the font is valid?

Comment: Yes the font work correctly in whole app but not here. Maybe I'm not understanding well what you are suggesting me. now I've changed the style like my edit.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant. I just did a quick test with a similar setup, and I observe the same thing. Hmm...

Comment: Your `@color/red` doesn't happen to be magenta, does it? That is, is its value `#FF00FF` or `#FFFF00FF`? My quick setup actually works; I just happened to use magenta as a test font color, and [that's currently being treated as indication of an error](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L2655), causing a default appearance and color to be applied.

Comment: Also, it seems that you can't set the text color through that `TextAppearance` by default, as the `counterTextColor` attribute is applied separately afterward. To prevent that, we need to set `app:counterTextColor="@null"` on the `<TextInputLayout>`. (That could probably be handled through a `textInputStyle` theme setting, if you'd rather, so you wouldn't have to set it on each one.)

Comment: You are right. Comment my question to receive my vote :-)

Comment: Did you get it working? `TextInputLayout` has turned into quite a little mess these days, and so many things about it are shaky and/or poorly documented.